# Get Custom Product Information Value

Tags: magento

I have amazon import script in my magento store. And each product has "Amazon Import Products" inside Product Information (Near General, Prices, Meta Information, Images...).

What I'm trying to get using PHP is located in "Amazon Import Products" And the value of "Amazon Product URL"

Here is my code to choose the product by SKU:

```
$sku = $id;
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); 
$amazonlink =
```

Can someone help? The only thing I can find online is how to get product name or images etc but not how to get custom attributes? Also this speed sensitive so I would like to fetch it by the name and not to loop through all the attributes

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$sku = $id;
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sku, 'sku'); 
$amazonlink = $_product->getData('custom_attributes_code_here');
// or 
$amazonlink = $_product->getCustomAttributesCodeHere();
```

Comment: I have tried `$amazonlink = $_product->getData('Amazon_Product_URL');` & `$_product->getAmazonProductUrl();` both didn't work

Comment: Try print_r($_product->getData());, do you see the amazon product url and is the array key 'amazon_product_url'?

Comment: got this only `Array`

Comment: If your getting an empty array then that product does NOT exist. try print_r($id); and print_r($_product->getId()); is the result a valid sku and product id?

Comment: exists but not in stock the code is wrong because `$short = $_product->getShortDescription();` works fine

Answer (score 0):

Below is the safest way to get custom attribute value.

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute_code');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
```

Above code is explained in my blog post here

[Getting custom attribute value in Magento](http://scriptbaker.com/get-custom-attribute-value-in-magento/)